# Sending Form Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

[This is the link that i'm working with](http://m.roblox.com/items/24826737/privatesales)

I'm trying to avoid using `form.submit` in order to purchase the item. The user clicks the item then must confirm the purchase. It isnt really a form that is sent but instead it runs a function [shown here](http://js.rbxcdn.com/9c4ebf2b6df44b2ee95c1116b9e4eede.js.gzip). You can use copy and paste the string and use control+F to go do to the part of the script where the function is held: (`;// pages/PurchaseConfirmationModal.js`)

I looked up the `POST` method and I wasnt able to really figure out how to get this to work;

```
$.post("Form here", // How to identify the form?
    function( data ) {
       // how do I send the data?
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the input fields in your form id:s, then you can get their value in order to pass it on for $.post, e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="input_one"/>
<input type="text" id="input_two"/>
```

And then:

```
var post_data={
    first_value: $("#input_one").val(),
    second_value: $("#input_two").val()
};

$.post("http://...",post_data,
    function(data) {
        // Handle the response from the server here.
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML PART**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="first_value" id="first_value" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="second_value" id="second_value" />

    <button id="submitForm" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**AJAX Part**
Call the function by clicking on the button.
Then gather your form data by using `$("input[id=first_value]").val()` or `$("#first_value").val()` Up to you.

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(event){     
    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {    
            'first'             :   $("input[id=first_value]").val(),
            'second'            :   $("input[id=first_value]").val(),   
    };


    // process the form
    var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
                                type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                                url         : 'someURL', // the url where we want to POST
                                data        : JSON.stringify( formData ),
                                contentType :'application/json',
                                error       : function(data,status,error){
                                                console.log(data+': '+status+': '+error);
                                                },
                                success     :  function(status) {
                                                    //DO something when the function is successful
                                                }       
                    }).done(function(apiResponse) {
                            //Do something when you are done
                    });

});
```